# Why is there a separate instance of VM(Dalvik/ART) for every App on Android?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik, vm-implementation

As the title states,
**Why is there a separate instance of VM(Dalvik/ART) for every App on Android?(the need for it)**

and, what would have happened if the Android OS had chosen a model where a single VM runs all the apps?

Comment: I know that Dalvik do that but ART. Are you sure?

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons why running multiple applications in a single process doesn't work; here's two:

#### Security zones.

Two applications that don't trust one another shouldn't be able to view each other's memory, even if they use native code or reflection.

#### Failure isolation.

If a process leaks memory and crashes, it harms only itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is a separate instance of VM(Dalvik/ART) for every App?(the
>   need for it)

It is a design decision, and in my opinion, is made to keep it simple. Every process runs in its own `vm`. All the resources are allocated to that process, and the `vm`, internally, has not to coordinate access to resources, e.g. `FileDescriptor`s, `I/O` etc. I never heard of `multiprocess vm` (a vm that allows more than one process to run in it), but I found an [article](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/1201) that you could give you an insight.